# Bulk operation on java synchronized cache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I would like to implement a simple cache, which is updated periodically, and every update triggers a full cache clear and data insertation.

Pseudocode:

```
//context calls periodically this method
cache.clear();
cache.putAll(newValues)
```

Since other threads might read the cache during the refresh operation. I need some kind of synchronization.

The simplest solution might be similar to the following:

```
computeNewCacheValues()
computeStaleKeys() //e.g. ones are in the cache but are not in the new cache
removeStaleKeysOneByOneFromCache()
updateKeysFromNewCacheValueOneByOne()
```

The implementation is backed by a ConccurentHashMap instance - so during cache updates:

- no concurrency issues occurs(?)
- the cache is not locked for the entire process (thus accessible during refresh)

This might be (?) a good solution, but I was wondering: are there other, more efficient/safe ways to implement this? Are there any libraries which are capable of this operation?

Comment: in your example you don't override existing items with new values, so they never change? then what's the point of so complicated replacement if you could just populate cache over time?

Comment: update the addKeysFromNewCacheValueOneByOne to updateKeysFromNewCacheValueOneBeOne; thanks!

Comment: then Peter's answer is just fine, it's better to atomically replace the whole cache than do these complicated update tricks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always replacing the entire cache you can just replace it.

```
final AtomicReference<Map<K, V>> mapRef = new AtomicReference<>();

// assuming you don't modify the map after calling this.
public void update(Map<K, V> map) {
    mapRef.set(map);
}

public V get(K key) {
    // this will always see the latest complete map.
    return mapRef.get().get(key);
}
```

Note: there is no locking required as the Map is not altered once it is added to the cache.

Comment: When calling mapRef.get().get(key) does this mean that a copy of map object is returned - thus every call on get does a copy operation? What happens, when two get operations get called concurrently?

Comment: @krisy a copy of the *reference* which is typical 4 bytes is taken every time.  The Map object is not copied.  If multiple thread call this at once, they will each have a copy of the reference to the Map, but there will be only one copy of the Map in memory. Note: it is essential that this Map not be altered for this to work without locks.  When you update the cache you have to create a new Map e.g. a HashMap each time. This new Map can be based on a copy of the old map.

Comment: One last question; in the (J8) source of the AtomicReference class, I see that under the hood a volatile variable is used. As I understand, all access to volatile variables work as if these accesses were synchronized. So, when two method concurrently call mapRef.get(), does this mean they will have sequential access, e.g. one thread will suspend, until the other finishes?

Comment: @krisy no locking is involved when you use `volatile` and you can have any number of concurrent readers safely.  You could use a simple `volatile Map map` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

When creating a "`bulk cache`", the simplest solution might be the one that @Peter mentioned; on a separate thread create the new cache, and change the reference of the old one to the new one.

Things to consider:

- the solution works, because the assignment operator ("`=`") execution is atomic
- the cache object must be `volatile`; this way its value is accessible to multiple threads (without this one thread might change its value, but the other thread will not be able to see the change)
- `AtomicReference` is another option; basically its a wrapper for a volatile object, although it adds some useful methods (e.g. for audit)